# Matrix with Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

When given matrix A and lambda=2 is an eigenvalue of the matrix. How do you find another eigenvalue of the matrix formed by 5A+7I?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try letting $v$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $2$ and calculating $(5A + 7I)v$.

Comment: I tried simplify (5A+7I)v using the property Av=2v

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

- Let $v$ be the eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $2$, that is $Av = 2v$.
- Compute $(5A+7I)v$.

Comment: We simplify (5A+7I)v using the property Av=2v

Comment: yup, that's right.

Comment: Replace v with 2v in the formula?

Comment: hmmm... what do you mean by replacing $v$ by $2v$? can you elaborate? Are you computing $(5A+7I)v$? we can replace $Av$ by $2v$, I don't see a justification of replacing $v$ by $2v$.

Comment: Do we need to use the Dot Product?

Comment: not explicitly though matrix multiplication consists of a bunch of dot products.

Comment: Then how do you simplify (5A+7I)?

Comment: use distributive law to compute $(5A+7I)v$.

Comment: Which would be 5Av+7Iv

Comment: Then it would be 5(2)+7Iv?

Comment: It is $5(2v)+7(v)$, now simplify and make conclusion. Note that in maths, for every single step that you take, try to give a justification.

Comment: That would be 10v+7v, which equals 17v

Comment: yup, hence the eigenvalue is $17$.